# Not able to Delete the Mongo index with django using pymongo

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, django-database, djongo

I have a simple model which is defined as(sample_app/models.py):

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

then I run

```
python3 manage.py makemigration sample_app
```

Migration is created. The run

```
python3 manage.py migrate sample_app
```

Migration is performed successfully.

I logged into mongo shell and checked the Indexes:

```
db.collectino_name.getIndexes()
Output-->

[
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
    "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "some_info"
},
{
  "v" : 2,
  "unique" : true,
  "key" : {
    "id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "__primary_key__",
  "ns" : "some_info"
},
{
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
    "field1" : 1
  },
  "name" : "some_info_field1_a59e0e95",
  "ns" : "some_info"
}
]
```

So the index has been created. Great.
**Now I want to remove the indexes.** I changed my model.py to look like this.

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then successfully run makemigration and but got an error while migrating.

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>                                                                                                              
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                               
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command
_line                                                                                                                                                 
    utility.execute()                                                                                                                                 
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute             
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                           
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv           
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                                                                                
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute                 
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)                                                                                                            
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped                  
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 203, in handle      
    fake_initial=fake_initial,                                                                                                                        
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate               
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                                  
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards 
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)                                                              
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration       
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)                                                                                                     
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply                
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)                                                              
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forw
ards                                                                                                                                                  
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)                                                                                       
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 523, in alter_field          
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)                                                                                                             
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 586, in _alter_field         
    index_names = self._constraint_names(model, [old_field.column], index=True, type_=Index.suffix)                                                   
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1047, in _constraint_names   
    if type_ is not None and infodict['type'] != type_:
KeyError: 'type'
```

Not able to perform the migration :(. *Here I am able to get the type_(i.e idx) value but not infodict['type']*

But If I delete the index from mongoshell(using dropIndex) then I am able to run the migration.

**So Any Idea what is problem underneath?**

Here is requirement.txt

```
pymongo==3.7.2
djongo==1.2.31
Django==2.1.7
coreschema==0.0.4
sqlparse==0.2.4
```

I have also checked these links.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/527